# Fibonacci Recursion Not working

Tags: java, recursion

I probably made some stupid mistake, but whenever I try to run this program it always gives me a wrong answer. For example, I ask what is the 5th value of the Fibonacci sequence and it says 7.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     // TODO add your handling code here:
    int n=0;
    try{
        n= Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());    
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        jTextField2.setText("Please enter valid integers.");
    }
    jTextField2.setText("Fibo value is"+Fibonacci(n));
}  

private int Fibonacci(int n){

    System.out.println(n+"N");
    if (n <=1) {
        return n;
    }
    else{
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+(n-2);        
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2);`

Comment: When implementing recursive programs try to expand manually in a paper the definitions and see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fib is recursively define as `Fib(n) = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)`.
Your program defines it as `Fib(n) = Fib(n-1) + (n-2)`

Answer:

```
int Fibonacci(int n) {

    System.out.println(n + "N");

    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find Fibonacci by binary recursion. You should make two recursive calls, like

```
return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
```

but you have made a mistake here -

```
return Fibonacci(n - 1) + (n - 2);
```

Your code can be fixed easily by

```
int Fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

The above recursion is called binary recursion since it makes two recursive calls instead of one.
Lets calculate the number of calls are needed to compute the kth Fibonacci number :-
Let nk denote the number of calls performed in the execution.

> n0 = 1
>   n1 = 1
>   n2 = n1 + n0 + 1  = 3 > 21
>   n3 = n2 + n1  + 1 = 5 > 22
>   n4 = n3 + n2 + 1 = 9 > 23
>   n5 = n4 + n3 + 1 = 15 > 23
>   ...
>   nk  > 2k/2

This means that the Fibonacci recursion makes a number of calls that are exponential in k.
In other words, using binary recursion to compute Fibonacci numbers is very inefficient.

This linear recursive version takes O(n) calls.

A more efficient solution :-

```
int fibonacci(int n) { 
   return fibonacciSlave(0, 1, n);
}

int fibonacciSlave(int a, int b, int n) { 
    if(n <= 1) {
       return b;
    }
   return fibonacciSlave(b, a+b, n-1);
}
```

Comment: The question isn't about how to make it more efficient, rather, what is wrong with his current solution. I downvoted because you failed to explain the latter.

Comment: I have already posted that in the comment. This is very trivial question. However, I will add some explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to improve the answer :)

Comment: I'd still say it's not a good answer. You explanation is "it's trivial", which doesn't even explain the error (though I didn't think that warranted a downvote).

Comment: @AjahnCharles, I have incorporated your suggestion